# How to execute an input asking utility in a loop within a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, solaris-10

I am trying to run an utility(nco_confpack) which works perfectly fine when used directly on command line. 
But when I am using the same utility in a while loop in a shell script the utility enters into infinite loop without accepting any input.
How to avoid that infinite loop for utility ?
Below is the code snippet which is working fine

```
bash-3.2$ $OMNIHOME/bin/nco_confpack -import -server SERVERA -user root -password XXXXX-select Class.list -package Class.jar
*********************************************************************
*                          W A R N I N G                            *
*                                                                   *
* This action may overwrite configuration currently in your system. *
*                                                                   *
* It is recommended that a backup is made of the current data       *
* before importing new data.                                        *
*                                                                   *
*********************************************************************
Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? y
bash-3.2$
```

However, when the same utility is placed in a while loop the *Do you want to continue(y/n)* message enters into a infinite loop without accepting any input

```
bash-3.2$ ./classInstall.sh
Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? Do you want to continue (y/n) [N]? ^C
```

What I am doing wrong here ? Is something wrong with the utility or do I have to mention something in script explicitly ?

*The script contains the same command just that its running under a finite while loop.*

```
bash-3.2$vi classInstall.sh
cat $1 | while read theLine
do
$OMNIHOME/bin/nco_confpack -import -server SERVERA -user root -password XXXXX-select Class.list -package Class.jar
done
```

*$1 contains two entries only so the loop , and the command is expected to run twice only*

Comment: Does the loop occur automatically, or does the prompt only repeat when you press enter?

Comment: It might help to show the code in question.

Comment: @NicolaiEhemann the loop occurs automatically before accepting anything from user/prompt.

Comment: I second chepners request. Your script obviously feeds input to the command, but we can't say how without inspecting it.

Comment: @NicolaiEhemann I have updated the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure *why* the while loop feeds your utility with line feeds, but you can solve the problem by feeding the expected 'y' to the utility yourself:

```
cat $1 | while read theLine
do
    echo y | $OMNIHOME/bin/nco_confpack -import -server SERVERA -user root -password XXXXX-select Class.list -package Class.jar
done
```

Comment: Thanks that worked .. Also I was able to search an in-built command for this . 
`cat $1 | while read theLine
do
    /usr/bin/yes | $OMNIHOME/bin/nco_confpack -import -server SERVERA -user root -password XXXXX-select Class.list -package Class.jar
done`
 Let me know if this is working for you also.